# MultiBinding in Xamarin Forms: element is null

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, multibinding

I'm trying to use MultiBinding with Xamarin.Forms 4.8, and I can't get it to work. I have this very simple converter:

```
public class QuantityLabelConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use it in an XAML label, like this:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource QuantityLabelConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedQuantity" />
            <Binding Path="OutstandingQuantity" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Now, when I debug, I can see that the converter is called three times: one with two null values, then another one when the SelectedQuantity value is set, and a last time when OutstandingQuantity value is assigned. So the link between the bindings and the converter seems to be working fine.

However, the page crashes and I get a "Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: element" System.ArgumentNullException.

If I replace the previous XAML with a simple

```
<Label Text="Hello World">
```

The page shows without problems, so there is something wrong with how the MultiBinding is set, but I don't know what...

Comment: Hi , any updates ?

Comment: Hi Lucas, sorry for the long delay, I had not had the chance to come back to this problem until today... and today it works without problems . I just reapplied the code that I had stashed in git last week, so... Either the XF update that was released after I posted the question fixed it (which seems probable), or I made a silly mistake first time and messed up when testing/trying to fix my code (which is also possible). Thanks a lot for your help, and I'll mark your answer as the solution, as I'm sure your detailed example will be helpful for others that start using MultiBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return **BindableProperty.UnsetValue** to use the binding FallbackValue .

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (!(value is string b))
            {
                return "xxx";
                // set a default value when unset
            }

        }

        string str1 = values[0].ToString();
        string str2 = values[1].ToString();

        return str1+str2;
    }
```

##Update

I had tested the sample and found out the cause

If you want to binding the property of ViewModel . You need to implement the interface **INotifyPropertyChanged** of the property instead of BindableObject .

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{



    string _name="";
    string _surname="";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(_name!=value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set
        {
            if(_surname!=value)
            {
                _surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (!(value is string b))
                {
                    return " ";
                    // set a default value when unset
                }

            }

            string str1 = values[0].ToString();
            string str2 = values[1].ToString();

            return str1 + str2;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, maybe today is not my brightest day, but... what is the difference? (I mean, I’m always returning a string value, regardless of the bound values)

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms are you using? I just found out this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12094. If you look at my comment there (I downloaded a sample project to test Multibinding), it seems that XF4.8 is broken :(  (Thanks a lot by the way for trying to help, that I forgot to mention it in my previous comment!)